# How can you SSH to a GKE node (Private/Public)?

Tags: ssh, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

SSH to GKE node private IP from the jump server (Bastion host) is not working.

I even tried the following as suggested by one of my friends, but it did not help.

```
gcloud compute instances add-metadata $INSTANCE_NAME_OR_INSTANCE_ID --metadata block-project-ssh-keys=false --zone $YOUR_VM_ZONE --project $YOUR_PROJECT
```

Also please confirm if the solution works for Private GKE too.

Comment: if you want to ssh from a bastion host be sure the's a firewall rule that allows it. Also, if you have an error while performing the ssh call, please post it

Comment: a firewall rule is already in place. I'm seeing Connection timed out. Also what username should I give when doing SSH?

Answer (score 3):

GKE node is just a GCE VM. You can just access it as a normal GCE instance if with proper privilege and ssh key configured.

One thing worth to mention that [GCP support IAP based ssh port forwarding](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/using-tcp-forwarding#tunneling_with_ssh)

Comment: You do not have the option to edit the instance as the instance group and template were automatically generated when you create the gke cluster.

Comment: what username should I give when doing SSH?

Comment: I cannot SSH to the GKE node GCE VMs using euther Web SSH or $ gcloud compute ssh --zone us-west1-b gke-xxx-default-pool-yyy-3q77 -- ps
ssh: connect to host 35.100.100.10 port 22: Connection timed out

Answer (score 1):

I have added my ssh keys using gcloud CLI, as in the console the edit option is disabled for all gke nodes.

Now I'm able to do SSH.